# How do you get the x and y coordinates of an uncompressed public key?

Tags: cryptography, public-key

the question says it all. I want to get the x and y coordinates of an uncompressed public key such as this one but I'm not sure how: 0x049063c5815255596f680d1f94a4258e20eaa470a7e7557f01bd6cdcfcd44239168acb9f6f24fcd3a05f9f6aec43f6e2042de2b97fe5aa6a758f6962ac6271bf31

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, I'm very new to cryptography. I wasn't removing the 0x04 prefix when trying to get the coordinates. For anyone interested this is how you can do it in nodejs:

```
const pubKeyString = '0x049063c5815255596f680d1f94a4258e20eaa470a7e7557f01bd6cdcfcd44239168acb9f6f24fcd3a05f9f6aec43f6e2042de2b97fe5aa6a758f6962ac6271bf31';
const coordsString = pubKeyString.slice(4, pubKeyString.length); // removes 0x04
const x = BigInt('0x' + coordsString.slice(0, 64)); // x is the first half
const y = BigInt('0x' + coordsString.slice(64, coordsString.length)); // y is the second half
```